# fijar una imagen con html sin usar css

Tags: html

tengo este codigo y quiero poner mi imgen fija en el fondo pero me salen 3 y solo ocupo poner 1 de fondo y pues con su informacion que corresponde apoyo porfavor.

```
<?php

$cuerpo = '<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:TitilliumWeb-Regular;color:#006a87">

    <body background="/application/assets/img/PajaroWatermark500x640.png" bgcolor="ffffff"; > 

        <center>
            <div style="width:500px;height:60px;background-color:#ffffff;border-radius:20px">

                <div style="width:100%;height:50px;background-color:#006a87;border-top-left-radius:10px;border-top-right-radius:10px; padding-top:20px;">

                <img style="height:30px "src="http://sandbox.balun.mx/application/assets/img/logof.png" style="margin-top:30px;margin:30px"/>

                </div><br>
                 <img src="http:../application/assets/img/277x50GuiasGeneradas.png" style="margin-top:20px; margin:30px" />
                 <br>
                 <br>

                 <font color=#006a87><b>Se han generado guías en su cuenta, Hemos adjuntado la(s) guía(s) en formato *.PDF</font></b>
                 <br>
                 <br>
                 <br>

                <font color=#006a87><b>Haga click  en el número de guía para rastreo: <a href="http://">32135465</a></b><br>
                <br>
                 <br>
                 <br>

                <p><b>Atentamente</b></p>
                <p><small><b>el equipo de</b> </small> </p>
         <img style="height:20px;widht:20px" src="http:../application/assets/img/277x50Logo.png" style="margin-top:50px" />

            </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html> ';

    echo  $cuerpo;   ?>
```

Comment: Hola! ¿A qué se refiere con que salen 3 imágenes? Te refieres a que la imagen de fondo sale repetida?

Comment: es correcto y solo ocupo 1 imagen de fondo para poner los textos

Comment: Vale. Pues escribe en el CSS `background-repeat: no-repeat` y así no se repetirá más.

Comment: en el css si me queda muy bien... pero el que me lo pide tiene que estar con ese codigo... si me explico, no puede tener css porque no jalara en su sitema me comenta.

Comment: Intenta poner `!important` al final de la línea del CSS, así este estilo tendrá 'privilegios'. Con lo cual quedaría: `background-repeat: no-repeat !important; `

Comment: lo mande con css, y te comento ahi esta bien perfrecto la imagen me queda bien y todo, pero lo quiere sin css, porque lo subira a su sistema y tiene que ir los codigos asi me ando desesperando porque no agarra asi, lo unico que me dijo fue que por mi body background es que las imagenes se hacen asi debe de estar en un style. pero no me sale

Comment: Entonces no puedes usar nada de CSS porque lo quieren sin él. Has probado metiendo en un `style` lo de `background-repeat: no-repeat` y sigue sin funcionar. Cierto?

Comment: si es correcto.

Comment: Vale. Prueba poner detrás de las URL `no-repeat`, de tal manera que quede: `style = "background: url('/application/assets/img/PajaroWatermark500x640.png') no-repeat;"`

Comment: se me desaparece la imagen por completo queda en blanco total. rayoss rayos...

Comment: ya regreso la imagen me falto " pero sigue sin ponerse esa imagen ahora no aparece nada de imagen de fondo

Comment: Uffff a ver, prueba otra cosa. `style = "background-image: url('/application/assets/img/PajaroWatermark500x640.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat"` y tambén prueba esto `style = "background-image: url('/application/assets/img/PajaroWatermark500x640.png') no-repeat"`

Comment: pues no, nada mas no quiere jalar, pero muchísimas gracias, te agradezco de corazón tu apoyo, si ya no hay opciones pues ahorita veo que puedo hacer. gracias nuevamente.

Comment: En la pagina w3schools encuentras esto: "The <body> background attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead." Esto quiere decir que si o si debes usar estilos CSS aunque no invoques archivos CSS externos. Prueba con esto: `<body background="/application/assets/img/PajaroWatermark500x640.png" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;">`

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes hacer es usar una imagen de alta definición, así ocupará todo el espacio del navegador y no se repetirá. Estoy probando con una de 2560 x 1536 px y no se repite.

Comment: con este codigo jalo  <?php

    
    <body bgcolor="ffffff" style="font-family:TitilliumWeb-Regular;color:#006a87"> 
     <style> body{}  #main{border-style:solid;border-color:-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 8px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   -moz-box-shadow: 7px 8px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   box-shadow: 7px 8px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);}</style>
      
muchisimas gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo usando una imagen de alta definición. Prueba de esta manera.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:TitilliumWeb-Regular;color:#006a87">

    <body background="https://picsum.photos/1200/1800/?gravity=east"> 

        <center>
            <div style="width:500px;height:60px;background-color:#ffffff;border-radius:20px">

                <div style="width:100%;height:50px;background-color:#006a87;border-top-left-radius:10px;border-top-right-radius:10px; padding-top:20px;">

                <img style="height:30px "src="http://sandbox.balun.mx/application/assets/img/logof.png" style="margin-top:30px;margin:30px"/>

                </div><br>
                 <img src="http:../application/assets/img/277x50GuiasGeneradas.png" style="margin-top:20px; margin:30px" />
                 <br>
                 <br>

                 <font color=#006a87><b>Se han generado guías en su cuenta, Hemos adjuntado la(s) guía(s) en formato *.PDF</font></b>
                 <br>
                 <br>
                 <br>

                <font color=#006a87><b>Haga click  en el número de guía para rastreo: <a href="http://">32135465</a></b><br>
                <br>
                 <br>
                 <br>

                <p><b>Atentamente</b></p>
                <p><small><b>el equipo de</b> </small> </p>
         <img style="height:20px;widht:20px" src="http:../application/assets/img/277x50Logo.png" style="margin-top:50px" />

            </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```